# If Else Conditionals within Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with conditionals. I want to return the index where pattern starts in string (or -1 if not found). The search is to be case sensitive if the 3rd parameter is true otherwise it is case insensitive.

```
Examples
index("abAB12","AB",true) returns 2 but index("abAB12","AB",false) returns 0
index("abAB12","BA",true) returns -1 and index("abAB12","BA",false) returns 1
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

This is my code so far

```
var s = "abAB12"
var p = "AB"
var cs = true

    function index(string, pattern, caseSensitive) {

        if (pattern) {

            var found = false;

            if (caseSensitive = false) {
                if (string.indexOf(pattern.) >= 0) {
                    found = true;
                }
                return (found);
                else {
                    return ("");
                }
            } else if (caseSensitive = true) {
                if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    found = true;
                }
                return (found);
            } else {
                return ("");
            }
        }

    }

alert(index(s, p, cs));
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/AfDFb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistype in your code. On the 15th line you have

```
}
return (found);
else {
```

This is not not valid. Change it to

```
return (found);
}
else {
```

There is another one.

```
if (caseSensitive = false) {
```

`=` used for assignment. You need to use `==` in if statements when comparing.
Also on the 13th line, there's an extra `.` after pattern. Remove it.

```
if (string.indexOf(pattern.) >= 0) {
```

[Your fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AfDFb/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`string.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsearch) with a regular expression to accomplish this in one liner:

```
function index(input, key, caseMatters) {
    return input.search(new RegExp(key, caseMatters ? '' : 'i'));
}
```

Now you can:

```
index("abAB12","AB",true); // returns 2
index("abAB12","AB",false); // returns 0
index("abAB12","BA",true); // returns -1
index("abAB12","BA",false); // returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value inside if condition instead of comparing it.

Try

```
 if (caseSensitive == false) {
```

and

```
 if(caseSensitive == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double equals sign `==` in your `if, else` statements.

```
if(caseSensitive == false)
```

And

```
if(caseSensitive == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `search` :

```
'abAB12'.search(/AB/); // 2
'abAB12'.search(/AB/i); // 0
'abAB12'.search(/BA/); // -1
'abAB12'.search(/BA/i); // 1
```

The `i` flag means "case `i`nsensitive" ( `i`nsensible à la casse :D ).